# namespace of a parameter in new defined function

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, namespaces

What happens when I define a function in a function and both share the same varable name? e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(

$("a").on("click", function( event )
{
   // function code goes here
   function newfunction( event )
   {
     // function code dependant on parameter "event" goes here. 
     // Is "event" now a new variable totally independant to the first 
     // parameter "event". Were do I find something concerning the 
     // topic in the jQuery documentary?
   }
}

);

);
```

Is the second "event" in line 6 totally independant from the first "event" in line 3? I coun't finde anything to namespaces in the documentary

http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/

of jQuery. Where do I have to look there?

Comment: They are different variables. Yes. This is a javaScript feature and not jQuery.Try searching "javascript parameter scope" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment: They are different variables. Yes. This is a javaScript feature and not jQuery.Try searching "javascript parameter scope" or similar.

Ignoring the other details, all you have is 2 functions nested. The scope of a parameter variable is within the braces of that function only.

```
function a(p1){
  // Can only see p1 here
  function b(p2){
    // can see p2 and p1 here
  }
}
```

If the names match that of an outer variable, the closest scope to the code wins

```
function a(p){
  // Can only see first p here
  function b(p){
    // can see second p here as the first is now hidden by the new definition
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found an explanation for your second example in the o'Reilly book. It says, that parameters in a function have higher priority than the ones outside the function. One is effectivly hiding the variable p inside of b when one uses the same variable name p again. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `event` on the newfunction is a parameter.  As such it's value will be whatever is passed to that method when it is called.  It is not tied directly to the parameter on the click handler.  If you want it to be the event parameter from the click handler, then do not put that name on your newfunction method.  The event from the click handler will be available inside newfunction when it is called since it is defined in the scope of the click handler.